# How do I ignore all pathNames and load my index.php at the root of my site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When a user clicks a nav link on my web site it loads the page into a content window on the current page with javascript.

I then use HTML 5 to manipulate the URL and create a history entry. So the URL I am left with looks like the one in the question (https://someDomain.com/questions).

The problem is if I click refresh or send someone the a link it gets a 404 error because it is going to the pathname /questions and is then looking for an index.

In my case I am loading (pages/questions.php).

Is there a way to make it so my domain ignores all pathNames or something so I can then use the location.pathname to do my page loading into my Main index.php at the root of the domain...

Here is my current .htaccess code

```
#default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php

#PHP code in HTML file
AddType cgi-script .php .htm .html .phtml

RewriteRule ^/.*$ /index.php
```

Comment: Please show your code so that we may see what's going on.

Comment: So you want all requests to go to the root index.php, but changed so that index.php knows what is being requested?  Sounds like it might be a job for url rewriting.  I believe apache and nginx web servers have modules and configuration directives for that sort of thing.  If you can edit your question to be more specific, someone can help.

Comment: Another reason to edit is that your title suggests one question, "how does a Stack Overflow URL work?", and the body suggests another question, "how do I feed everything into the root index.php?".  A good title is important.

Comment: on a lot of hosting plans you can customize your error page, or set it to the home page, then any relative url would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be configured at your web server (e.g. Apache, IIS, etc.), by rewriting every URL to your `index.php`.

For example, in Apache it is done using [RewriteRules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) in `.htaccess`, for your case something like this will do it - send any request to the file index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If it's indeed Apache, you can check a more comprehensive solution for this at [WordPress' `.htaccess`](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess).

Comment: Thank you very much I had a feeling this was going to be done through the server. I added that line to my .htaccess amd I am still getting 404 errors. I have posted my .htaccess code in the question.